# how to replace some text with special character?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to highlight some sentences in a text and I created this function:

```
       function highlightReviewAux(content,text) {
            return content.replace(new RegExp(`\\b${text}\\b`, "gi"), match => {
                return '<span class="highlightText">' + match + '</span>';
            });
```

It works except for this content ". [...] I booked this for a very special occasion, trusting that (the current title( “5 star The best 1 bed in Shoreditch” "

I think it's for the special characters.
This is the error:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /\bNice wooden Bedroom floor showed poor care when decorating as white paint splatted all over it. [...] I booked this for a very special occasion, trusting that (the current title( “5 star The best 1 bed in Shoreditch” \b/: Unterminated group
```

Can you help me? I'm here for more than 2 hours and can't find the solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I see the problem

It was when your `text` had a parenthesis. I think the idea of creating a regexp from arbitrary text is causing problems, and may be unnecessary.

```js
function highlightReviewAux(content, text) {
  return content.replace(new RegExp(`\\b${text}\\b`, "gi"), match => {
    return '<span class="highlightText">' + match + '</span>';
  });
}


const content = ". [...] I booked this for a very special occasion, trusting that (the current title( “5 star The best 1 bed in Shoreditch” "
const text = "title("

console.log(highlightReviewAux(content, text))
```

#### Just split the content wherever you find the text, and then rejoin

When you rejoin, you can use your chosen replacement string as the joining string.

```js
function highlightReviewAux(content, text) {
  const parts = content.split(text);
  return parts.join(`<span class="highlightText">${text}</span>`)

}

const content = ". [...] I booked this for a very special occasion, trusting that (the current title( “5 star The best 1 bed in Shoreditch” "
const text = "title("

console.log(highlightReviewAux(content, text))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that when some string with special characters used by Regular Expressions like ".", "(" or ")" is passed through the `text` parameter, there is a high chance that creating that Regular Expression will fail. But there is a built-in solution for this:

```js
function highlightReviewAux(content,text) {
    return content.replace(/\\b(.+)\\b/gi, '<span class="highlightText">$1</span>')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to [escape some characters inside the string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/400316/10304804) when you generate the regular expression using the constructor, otherwise they will be interpreted and can generate the error you get.

The chars in this case would be: `.^$*+?()[{\|`

You can escape them by adding a \ in front of them.

```js
function highlightReviewAux(content, text) {
  let escapedText = text.replace(/[.^$*+?()[{\\|]/g, "\\$&");
  console.log(escapedText);
  return content.replace(new RegExp(`(${escapedText})`, "gi"), match => {
    return '<span class="highlightText">' + match + '</span>';
  });
}


let str = "[...] I booked this for a very special occasion, trusting that (the current title( “5 star The best 1 bed in Shoreditch” ";

console.log(highlightReviewAux(str, "title("))

console.log(highlightReviewAux(str, "[...]"));
```

Comment: None of these characters except the backslash (and the `^` at the start of a class) have to be escaped inside a character class. So instead of `[\.\^\$\*\+\?\(\)\[\{\\\|]` you can simply write `[.^$*+?()[{\\|]`